# Use variable in jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors, concatenation, onchange

In the function below, I'd like the `idurl` be the word apple with a suffix. The suffix is `number` containing a number. Example would be `apple12`.

But in the function below, I have trouble concatenating the variable `number` with the word apple.

```
function apple(number) {
  if (something === "0") {
    $('.onchange :checkbox[idurl="apple" + number]').prop('checked', false);
  } else {
    $('.onchange :checkbox[idurl="apple" + number]').prop('checked', true);
  }
};
```

I tried using extra " or [] but it hasn't been very succesfull so far. The variable `number` is not bein recognized as a variable and thus not concatenated with the word apple.

Comment: how would you concatenate a string to a variable? It's the same thing. The selector is just a string.

Comment: It's not a duplicate because that question asks how to go about mixing variables and selectors.  This question asks why the variable isn't being added to the output string.  This question asks for assistance with code, the other asks about the practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$('.onchange :checkbox[idurl="apple"' + number+']').prop('checked', false);
```

Breaking of string:

1st part `'.onchange :checkbox[idurl="apple"'`

2nd part number

3rd part of string `']'`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because it is inside your single quotes. Try this instead:

```
$('.onchange :checkbox[idurl="apple"' + number + ']').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function with an actual number where your number argument in the function is.  Also, javascript doesn't recognize variables in quotes, so you need to escape your single quotes.

`$('.onchange :checkbox[idurl="apple"' +number +']').prop('checked', false);`